# Selection is glitchy

Tags: select

I got a new PC and I downloaded Blender 2.79 and 2.8 (2.8 is full release). I'm trying to do stuff but it seems so... glitchy. I can hardly select whatever I want to. And it's really really hard to see but the screen brightness changes when I move the mouse around in Blender. It used to change view by itself and move the mouse around in 2.79 but now it's gone. I just don't know what to do. It's not about mouse, I unplugged it and it still happens. Here's a video about what happens:
https://youtu.be/8of1JAB2dkc

Comment: Had a similar issue, but it was 15 years ago. Wireless keyboard and mouse kit and I did not want the keyboard. Apparently it needed the  keyboard physically present to avoid phantom key presses, in the end I kept it in a draw near by. Based on your video I would also check what other software is running. Did you build the PC yourself? Because manufactures like to include a lot of bloatware these days.

Comment: Well, no. This is a laptop. And  what kind of other programs should cause this? Antivirus maybe?

Comment: Yes, start with antivirus. Then work your way through all the programs running on your machine. Do any non Blender programs suffer in the same way? Always check for GFX card updates.